# Double headerbox alignment

Tags: positioning, posters, baposter

I have a question whether it's possible to align headerbox from above and below at the same time. When I make a poster I use, for example,

```
\headerbox{Title}{name=resultsFlow,below=UpperHeaderBox,column=3,span=6}{...}
```

But if this headerbox (or 2 headerboxes with span=3) in between the UpperHeaderBox and LowerHeaderBox, can I use something like

```
\headerbox{Title}{name=resultsFlow,below=UpperHeaderBox,above=LowerHeaderBox,column=3,span=6}{...}
```

just to adjust the headerbox height?

Right now I'm using `\vspace{}` for that purpose, but I don't like such manual adjustment. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please add a minimal working code example to help us help you.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. As TeXnician indicated, it involves much more work to answer your question when you don't provide a MWE. Please always post a full MWE beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. You might want to look at the poster library that has just been added to the wonderful `tcolorbox` package. It is modeled on `baposter`, but enables all the `tcolorbox` syntax and capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is "yes", this is possible. I replaced `headerbox` with `posterbox` as `headerbox` is deprecated. It is essential that that boxes above and below the middle box have been declared before placing a box between them. Box 1-3 demonstrate syntax where box 3 will stretch to fill the space between boxes 1 and 2. Box 2 is placed at the bottom of the page manually using `row=0.85`, where 0.85 is 85% of the column height. Boxes 4-6 only occupy the space defined by their contents, but are aligned with the boxes in the first column (`column 0`).

This is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[landscape,a0paper]{baposter}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[pangram]{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\background{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%
    %the poster background color
    \fill[fill=lightgray!25] (current page.north west) rectangle (current page.south east);
    %the header
    \fill [fill=lightgray!75] (current page.north west) rectangle ([yshift=-\headerheight] current page.north east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}    

\begin{poster}{
        grid=false,
        columns=3, % how many columns 1-6
        colspacing=5.0mm, % spacing between the columns
        background=user, %user or none or plain
        headerheight=0.1\textheight,
        eyecatcher=true, %turn left logo on/off
        %posterbox environment options
        headerborder=closed, % see the baposter manual for the rest
        borderColor=green,
        headershape=rectangle,
        headershade=plain,
        headerColorOne=green!40!white,
        textborder=rectangle,
        boxshade=plain,
        boxColorOne=green!10!white,
        headerFontColor=black,
        textfont=\scriptsize, % font definition for body of posterbox
        headerfont=\scshape, % font definition for header of posterbox
        linewidth=3pt,
    }
    {\includegraphics[height=5em]{example-image-a}\hspace{1cm}} % Eyecatcher on the left
    {Title} 
    {Author} 
    {\includegraphics[height=5em]{example-image-b}} % Logo
    \begin{posterbox}[name=box1, column=0,row=0,span=1]{Box 1}
        \Blindtext[3][5]
    \end{posterbox}
    \begin{posterbox}[name=box2, column=0,row=0.85,span=1]{Box 2}
        \Blindtext[3][5]
    \end{posterbox}
    \begin{posterbox}[name=box3, column=0,below=box1,above=box2,span=1]{Box 3}
        \Blindtext[3][5]
    \end{posterbox}
    \begin{posterbox}[name=box4, column=1,row=0,span=1]{Box 4}
        \Blindtext[1][1]
    \end{posterbox}
    \begin{posterbox}[name=box5, column=1,below=box3,span=1]{Box 5}
        \Blindtext[2][2]
    \end{posterbox}
    \begin{posterbox}[name=box6, column=1,aligned=box3,span=1]{Box 6}
        \Blindtext[2][5]
    \end{posterbox}

\end{poster}
\end{document}
```

This is the output:

[image]